# radius only upper corners android

Tags: android, android-xml, cornerradius

I Need To Round Only Upper Corners Or Only Downers
it's code of xml file defined as background of EditText

```
<?xml versi encoding="utf-8"?>
<shapexmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<cornersandroid:radius="30dip"/>
</shape>
```

But it round whole 4 corners
it should round 2 corners Like It

[image: Image Sample 1]

And

[image: Image Sample 2]

Comment: I see all 4 corners round... It's the container, a central line, a text below the line, a text above it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, you an create custom drawable for you view.

Top radious

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:padding="10dip"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

   <solid android:color="#000000" />

   <corners
  android:bottomLeftRadius="10dip"
   android:bottomRightRadius="10dip"
  android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
   android:topRightRadius="0dip" />

  </shape>
```

Bottom radius

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="10dip"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#000000" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dip"
    android:topRightRadius="10dip" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Thank You, It Works Successfully

Answer (score 0):

for create shape drawable this tool is very useful check it out

> http://angrytools.com/android/button/